# Recoding multiple variables using tidyverse in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, recode

May be a silly question, I want to recode multiple variable in a tibble with multiple conditions.

Data example:

```
library(tidyverse)
s <- matrix(sample(1:15, 20, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4)
s <- as_tibble(s)
```

Which gives something like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     V1    V2    V3    V4
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    11     2     5    14
2     5     4    15     5
3    13    15     2     5
4     7    13    15    11
5    11     5    12     3
```

I want to recode V1, V2, V3 with this conditions, and leaving V4 equal: 
if the value is less or equal to 5 get 1, if the value is more than 5 but less or equal to 10 get 2 and finally if the value is more than 10 get 3.

The output should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
         V1    V2    V3    V4
      <int> <int> <int> <int>
    1    3     1     1     14
    2    1     1     3      5
    3    3     3     1      5
    4    2     3     3     11 
    5    3     1     3      3
```

I know about apply, sapply, vapply, but I would like to recode using functions from tidyverse package and in an elegant way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at `mutate_at` in dplyr. It's designed to apply the same function to multiple columns you can choose however you like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To elaborate on @MrFlick comment, you can use `mutate_at` in conjunction with the `case_when` function in dplyr. It would look like this:

```
s %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(V1:V3), 
            function(x) case_when(x <= 5 ~ 1, x <= 10 ~ 2, TRUE ~ 3))
```

this will give you:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
     V1    V2    V3    V4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     3     1     3     6
2     2     1     1     8
3     2     3     1    14
4     1     3     3    15
5     1     2     3     7
```

Comment: Although there is a typo in your V4 column but it works!!! Thanks for introducing me the mutate_at function!!!

Comment: where is the typo? Are you referring to the numbers being different? If so, that is just do to the fact the `sample` used different numbers when creating the matrix for me then when you did it.